# C# multiprocess access same file

Tags: c#, asp.net

i work on project that include a windows client app and ASP web page ...

windows app execute on web page server.
windows client and ASP web page work together on a same server and work on same shared file ...

i want safe access these file , windows app wait for web page to finish work on file and/or web page wait windows app for finish work on these file ..

i use `EventWaitHandle waithandle=new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "SI_handle");` in both windows app and ASP web page

and on both ASP web page and windows app use `waithandle.WaitOne();` before access file and `waithandle.Set();` after finish workin on files .

my problem is windows app o web page wait forever on `waithandle.WaitOne();` and app or webpage freeze on it .

whats my wrong ?

windows or webpage code like this :

```
if (File.Exists(xml_path))
{
    waithandle.WaitOne();
    // work on file
    waithandle.Set();
}
```

Comment: If you have the same code in both the web app and windows app, its obvious what is happening. They are both hitting the "waitone" at the same time, and since they are both waiting, it'll never get to the set. You need to rethink your wait handle logic.

Comment: tested this idea with two processes and it actually seems to work. are you sure you are not getting an exception before the `waitHandle.Set()`? You should definitely use `try..finally` here,

Comment: @MichaelSander i addedd try..finally and wont work :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you simply use the OS to help you out here, because you can [open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725(v=vs.110).aspx) a file specifying that access should not be shared, by specifying [`FileShare.None`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx). As in:

```
try
{
    using (var stream = File.Open("my file name", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
    {
        // Do with it what you want.
    }
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    if (IsFileLocked(ex)
        // try later.
    else
        // report error.
}

...

const int ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION = 32;
const int ERROR_LOCK_VIOLATION = 33;

private static bool IsFileLocked(Exception exception)
{
    int errorCode = Marshal.GetHRForException(exception) & ((1 << 16) - 1);
    return errorCode == ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION || errorCode == ERROR_LOCK_VIOLATION;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When each application on the machine starts, they will need to [open system mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c41ybyt3(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example - create a global varaible in each application:

```
System.Threading.Mutex _multiAppMutex = null;

// application start logic
try
{
    _multiAppMutex = System.Threading.Mutex.OpenExisting("MultiApp");
}
catch 
{
    // the only reason we should be here it because this app is the first one to start
    _multiAppMutex = new System.Threading.Mutex("MultiApp");
}
```

And then in any code you want sync you would use that system mutex

```
if (File.Exists(xml_path))
{
    _multiAppMutex.WaitOne();
    // work on file
    _multiAppMutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Comment: 'System.Threading.Mutex' does not contain a definition for 'Set' and no extension method 'Set' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Threading.Mutex' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)r

Comment: I corrected the code.  It's [Mutex.ReleaseMutex Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.releasemutex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)